# '#' letter is missing in HttpContext.Request or HttpContext.Current.Request url?

Tags: c#, url, httpcontext

My URL is: `http://localhost/myApp/app/job/7#/Nmbr`

When I tried to get the URL from HttpContext.Request or HttpContext.Current.Request,
the given url is : `/myApp/app/job/7`

`#` and everything after this letter are missing? Why? How can I get the real current url?

Answer (score 2):

Http requests do not include anything after `#` (The browser does not send it with the request.)

`#` Is intended to allow for parameters to be specified for the browser only (Anchor target location, or with often with web 2.0 JavaScript parameters)

In order to pass parameters to the server use `?` that appears before the `#`

Here is some [information](https://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/03/01/6-things-you-should-know-about-fragment-urls/) regarding fragments (The part of the URL after `#`)

Comment: But I m using angular ui-router. So '#' should be used for routing mecanism in this plugin. Maybe I should found another way :S

Comment: It is only ever seen, or used on the client. When you come to an angular page without the `#` it will redirect you to the `otherwise` clause in your routing configuration. When it does this redirect, it will effectively only change the part after `#`, and not make a request to the server (since the server resource identified with the URL has not changed and all processing is done in javascript)

Comment: Indeed. The fragment isn't send to the server. You can't get it there, period.

Answer (score 1):

The Fragment property gets any text following a fragment marker (#) in the URI, including the fragment marker itself. Given the URI http://www.contoso.com/index.htm#main, the Fragment property would return #main.

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.fragment(v=vs.110).aspx
```

Comment: Won't work since the fragment isn't send to the server.